# Measurability of the product $[0,\infty]\times[0,\infty]\to[0,\infty]$

Tags: measure-theory

Is the function $[0,\infty]\times[0,\infty]\longrightarrow[0,\infty]$, $(x,y)\longmapsto xy$ Borel-measurable (with formal multiplication $0\cdot\infty=0$)? It clearly is, if $[0,\infty]$ is replaced by $\mathbb{R}$, because then the function is even continous. But the way I defined it, it is not - the Sequence $(n,1/n)$ tends to $(\infty,0)$, whereas its image is constantly $1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is enough to consider preimages under multiplication of neighborhoods of $\infty$, since multiplication is continuous for pairs of finite numbers. Let $\alpha$ be a positive number and let $V$ be the set $\{x\in[0,\infty]~:~x>\alpha\}$. The preimage of $V$ under multiplication consists of $\{\infty\}\times(0,\infty]\cup(0,\infty]\times\{\infty\}$ and the preimages under multiplication of finite numbers greater than $\alpha$. These are all Borel sets.

Answer (score 0):

Denote by $f$ such function. Then 
$$
f^{-1}(\{\infty\})=\{(\infty,\infty)\} \cup \{(\infty,y): 0<y<\infty\} \cup \{(x,\infty): 0<x<\infty\},
$$
which is measurable. Also,
$$
f^{-1}(\{0\})=\{(x,0): 0\le x\le \infty\} \cup \{(0,y): 0\le y\le \infty\},
$$
which is measurable. The rest is straighforward because you can reason on the restriction of $f$ to $[0,\infty)^2$.